# Set condition based on CPU-Arch in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile, buildx

I need to download and install a package directly from GitHub and I need to install some libraries I need for a build from source through `pip` down the line.

For that I use:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libavformat-dev libavdevice-dev libavfilter-dev libswscale-dev
```

and

```
RUN wget https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.30.0/geckodriver-v0.30.0-linux64.tar.gz \
&& tar -xf geckodriver-v0.30.0-linux64.tar.gz \
&& mv geckodriver /usr/local/bin/ \
&& rm geckodriver-v0.30.0-linux64.tar.gz
```

I want to build for different platforms with buildx:
`docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64,linux/arm64,linux/arm/v7 .`

On `amd64` I do not need to install the av libraries, as pip won't need to build anything, because wheels are provided.
On `arm64` and `arm/v7` I need to install the libraries, and I need to download, extract and copy a different `geckodriver` package.

Is there a way to specify conditional statements based on CPU architecture?

Answer (score 1):

Following [this docker blog post](https://www.docker.com/blog/faster-multi-platform-builds-dockerfile-cross-compilation-guide/) you have some predefined `ARG` variables like `BUILDPLATFORM` that you can use to build your image.

Therefore, you can try something like this:

```
FROM alpine as arm64
RUN echo "arm64" > /version.txt

FROM alpine as amd64
RUN echo "amd64" > /version.txt

FROM $TARGETARCH as common
RUN date >> /version.txt

CMD ["cat", "/version.txt"]
```

And use docker buildx to compile the image for multiple platforms:

```bash
$ docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64 -t test .
$ docker run --rm test
WARNING: The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match the detected host platform (linux/arm64/v8) and no specific platform was requested
amd64
Thu May 25 07:54:34 UTC 2023
```

```
$ docker buildx build --platform linux/arm64 -t test .
$ docker run --rm test
arm64
Thu May 25 07:53:09 UTC 2023
```

Answer (score 0):

As Daniel mentioned, Docker provides predefined [environmental variables that are accessible at container build time](https://docs.docker.com/build/guide/multi-platform/).

We don't need to do anything Docker specific with these however, we can simply use them in a bash script condition:

```bash
FROM python:3-bullseye

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y ffmpeg firefox-esr npm
ARG TARGETARCH
RUN if [ $TARGETARCH = "arm64" ]; then \
        apt-get install -y libavformat-dev libavdevice-dev python3-av \
    ; fi
RUN npm install -g webdriver-manager
RUN webdriver-manager update --gecko
```

Note the necessary specification of `ARG TARGETARCH` to make that environmental variable accessible by dispatched processes at build time.